# Having output issues utilizing pointers for branching and looping in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement, for-loop

This is a homework assignment that requiresthe use of pointers to output messages when a input value is divisible 3, by 5, and by 3 & 5. The code compiles and runs, but I'm not getting the desired output. Also, I am not certain what needs changing. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using std::istream;

int main()
{
    const int i{3};                      // Variable initialization and declaration
    long* pnumber{};                     // Pointer definition and initialization
    long number1 {};                     // Declaration and initialization of variable number1
    long number2 [i];                    // Declaration and initialization of variable containing array of 3L numbers
    char indicator{ 'n' };               // Continue or not?

    pnumber = &number1;                  // Store address in a pointer

    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "Please enter any number less than 2 billion, "
             << "then press the Enter key: ";
        cin  >> number1;

        if (*pnumber % 3 == 0)           // Test if remainder after dividing by 3 is 0  
        {
            cout << endl
                << "Number: " << number1
                << "-Fizz" << endl
                << endl << "Do you want to enter another value (please enter y or n? ";
            cin >> indicator;           // Read indicator
            if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
                break;                  // Exit from loop
        }

        if (*pnumber % 5 == 0)         // Test if remainder after dividing by 5 is 0  
        {
            cout << endl
                << "Number: " << number1
                << "-Buzz" << endl
                << endl << "Do you want to enter another value (please enter y or n? ";
            cin >> indicator;         // Read indicator
            if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
                break;                // Exit from loop
        }

        if ((*pnumber % 3 == 0) && (*pnumber % 5 == 0))    // Test if remainder after dividing by 5 and 3 is 0 
        {
            cout << endl
                << "Number: " << number1
                << "-FizzBuzz" << endl
                << endl << "Do you want to enter another value (please enter y or n? ";
            cin >> indicator;         // Read indicator
            if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
                break;                // Exit from loop
        }

        else
        {
            cout << endl              // Default: here if not divisible by 3 or 5  
                << "Please enter another number."


                << endl << "Do you want to enter another value (please enter y or n? ";
            cin >> indicator;         // Read indicator
            if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
                break;                // Exit from loop
        }
    }

    pnumber = &number2 [i];               // Change pointer to address of number2

    for (;;)
    {
        cout << endl << endl 
             << "Please enter an array of number(s), where the number is less than 2 billion, "
             << "then press the Enter key: ";
        cin >> number2 [i];

        if (*pnumber % 3 == 0)           // Test if remainder after dividing by 3 is 0  
        {
            cout << endl
                << "Number: " << number2
                << "-Fizz" << endl
                << endl << "Do you want to enter another array (please enter y or n? ";
            cin >> indicator;           // Read indicator
            if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
                break;                  // Exit from loop
        }

        if (*pnumber % 5 == 0)         // Test if remainder after dividing by 5 is 0  
        {
            cout << endl
                << "Number: " << number2
                << "-Buzz" << endl
                << endl << "Do you want to enter another array (please enter y or n? ";
            cin >> indicator;         // Read indicator
            if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
                break;                // Exit from loop
        }

        if ((*pnumber % 3 == 0) && (*pnumber % 5 == 0))    // Test if remainder after dividing by 5 and 3 is 0 
        {
            cout << endl
                << "Number: " << number2
                << "-FizzBuzz" << endl
                << endl << "Do you want to enter another value (please enter y or n? ";
            cin >> indicator;         // Read indicator
            if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
                break;                // Exit from loop
        }

        else
        {
            cout << endl              // Default: here if not divisible by 3 or 5  
                << "Please enter another number."


                << endl << "Do you want to enter another value (please enter y or n? ";
            cin >> indicator;         // Read indicator
            if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
                break;                // Exit from loop
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what *error* exactly are you getting? Have a look at this post about some suggestions when asking for help with homework assignments: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: The issue is the number2 output in the second part of the code while entering several numbers. It outputs Number: 008FFA88-Fizz instead of if I entered 6 it should output Number: 6-Fizz.

Comment: Why `using std::istream` with `using namespace std`?

Answer (score 0):

From your own I could figure out that you want to print `Fizz` when the input is completely divisible by `3` , print `Buzz` when the input is completely divisible by `5`and print `FizzBuzz` when its divisible by `3` and `5` both. Now, if my assumption is correct than you are making a logical mistake here. I will make it clear with an example.

Lets say the input number is `30`. Your program will find it is divisible by `3` so it will print `Fizz`, then similarly it will find that it is divisible by `5` so it will print `Buzz` also. And in the end for the same reason it will print `FizzBuzz` also. While you wanted to print only `FizzBuzz`.

This is how you should solve this problem.

```
        // First check if it is divisible by both 3 and 5 ?
    if ((*pnumber % 3 == 0) && (*pnumber % 5 == 0))    // Test if remainder after dividing by 5 and 3 is 0 
    {
        cout << endl
            << "Number: " << number2
            << "-FizzBuzz" << endl
            << endl << "Do you want to enter another value (please enter y or n? ";
        cin >> indicator;         // Read indicator
        if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
            break;                // Exit from loop
    }
    // if not, then is it divisible by 3 only ?
    else if (*pnumber % 3 == 0)           // Test if remainder after dividing by 3 is 0  
    {
        cout << endl
            << "Number: " << number2
            << "-Fizz" << endl
            << endl << "Do you want to enter another array (please enter y or n? ";
        cin >> indicator;           // Read indicator
        if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
            break;                  // Exit from loop
    }
    // if not, then is it divisible by 5 only?
    else if (*pnumber % 5 == 0)         // Test if remainder after dividing by 5 is 0  
    {
        cout << endl
            << "Number: " << number2
            << "-Buzz" << endl
            << endl << "Do you want to enter another array (please enter y or n? ";
        cin >> indicator;         // Read indicator
        if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
            break;                // Exit from loop
    }
    // everything else ...
    else
    {
        cout << endl              // Default: here if not divisible by 3 or 5  
            << "Please enter another number."


            << endl << "Do you want to enter another value (please enter y or n? ";
        cin >> indicator;         // Read indicator
        if (('n' == indicator) || ('N' == indicator))
            break;                // Exit from loop
    }
```

Comment: The issue now is the number2 output in the second part of the code while entering several numbers. It outputs Number: 008FFA88-Fizz instead of if I entered 6 it should output Number: 6-Fizz.

Comment: That's because you are not correctly assigning the array of integers to the `pnumber` pointer. Look at https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/pointers-arrays for better understanding of handling array using pointers

Comment: I tried using &number2 without [i] but it throws an error.

Comment: As you have declared `number2` as an array. so number2 itself would be a pointer to the address of the first element in the array. so you should use `pnumber = number2` instead of `pnumber = &number2`.

Comment: When the code is written as pnumber = number2 it causes a logic error and does not run correctly. The program will not output the number input into it

Comment: Please try including some examples in your queries. Though I guess you are expecting the second part of the code to accept an array of integers but you are using `cin` only once, instead you must use a loop under which you keep on taking an integer as an input and then use the whole logic under that loop only to classify that number to appropriate category and than repeat for other inputs.

Comment: That makes since but the teacher wants the numbers to be included all at once separated by comas

Comment: No problem ..you can easily get all the input first in an array using a loop. and then process the each element in a separate loop i.e. use `*(pnumber + idx )` to access each element at `idx`. Let me know you still have any problem.

Comment: The problem I'm having now is this week he now wants us to add a switch statement to the code building upon what we already have and also use a function and a multidimensional in this code. Maybe by possibly giving the out put when the various positions within the array are called?

Comment: sorry @phoenixCoder your problem does not seems to be very clear. and you can use switch statement instead of if-else statement for the same purpose. You can read about how switch statement works

Comment: I understand how the switch works I am just unsure how to convert the if statements in this code into a switch statement

Comment: These are the instructions:       1) Use of the Fizzbuzz logic from 
                                                 2) Use of a multidimensional array
                 3) Use of a function with a return value and input parameters
4) Use of a switch statement.

Comment: I have setup a multidimensional array and it is suppose to take user input and select a position within the array and make an output based on that once the number it outputs is divisible by 3 and 5.

Comment: How exactly would I begin to convert these if-else statements into a switch statement? I thought the mathematical expressions such as (*pnumber % 3 == 0) were not valid to use within the switch?

Comment: As in c/c++ it is not possible to use a non-constant expressions under `case` label in switch-case statements, you can use nested switch case to solve your problem. you can look at this https://ideone.com/BXFNCW for reference. And I don't understand what is the purpose of using multidimensional array.

Comment: We are supposed to have a multi dimensional array containing numbers that through user input for array location will yield a number that will then be checked by the FizzBuzz logic.